# Return type: Require properties of a specific type, but allow it to be partial

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in typescript:
I want to force the return type of a method to be a subset of an interface. So, in other words: All properties on the returned object have to exist on the interface, but not all of them are required.

Background: The partial state update of react.
I just had a bug where I renamed a property of the state but forgot to rename one occurrence in `getDerivedStateFromProps` because typescript doesn't actually know, that it is supposed to be the same type

Example:

```
interface IComponentState {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(
    props: IComponentProps, state: IComponentState) : IComponentState {
    if(some condition)
        return { property1: 'foo'}; // valid
    else
        return { property3: 'bar'}; // invalid, property3 does not exist on IComponentState

}
```

How do I have to specify the return type of `getDerivedStateFromProps` for this to work.
Marking all properties in `IComponentState` as optional is not what I am looking for, I am hoping for another solution.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions to use Partial<IComponentState>, if an IComponentState really is an object with two **optional** properties, then you should simply make these properties optional: `property1?: string;`.

Comment: @JBNizet: Sure, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Then Partial is what you should use. You can't return an IComponentState, since  its properties are not optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the use of `Partial<T>`?

```
interface IComponentState {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
}

function getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state: IComponentState): Partial<IComponentState> {
    if (props)
        return { property1: 'foo' }; // valid
    else
        return { property3: 'bar' }; // invalid, property3 does not exist on IComponentState

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `Partial<T>`:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(
    props: IComponentProps, state: IComponentState) : Partial<IComponentState> {
    if(some condition)
        return { property1: 'foo'}; // valid
    else
        return { property3: 'bar'}; // invalid, property3 does not exist on IComponentState

}
```